# Reactjs testing conditionnal rendering (snapshot)

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, snapshot

I'm trying to test my ReactJS application but I have an issue.
I have a header that is rendered in a certain way for the first page of the application and this header will change in all the other pages. I'm managing the changes using the current location from `react-router-dom`.
I don't know how to test that depending on the url, the header changes.
Right now I'm doing basic stuff in my test file :

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import HeaderSto from './HeaderSto';
import '../../setupTests';

describe("HeaderSto", () => {

    it("should render my component", () => {
        process.env.REACT_APP_MERCHANT = "merchant";
        const wrapper = shallow(<HeaderSto />);
        expect.anything(wrapper);
    });

    it("should render LandingPage header layout", () => {
        process.env.REACT_APP_MERCHANT = "merchant";
        window.location.assign = jest.fn();
        const tree = shallow(<HeaderSto />);
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

And the component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Row, Col } from 'antd';

class HeaderSto extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            CurrentRoute: ""
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            CurrentRoute: this.props.CurrentRoute
        });
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            CurrentRoute: nextProps["CurrentRoute"]
        });
    }

    renderGeneralHeader() {

        return(<div>Hi</div>);
    }

    renderLandingPageHeader() {

        const logo = require("../../images/" + process.env.REACT_APP_MERCHANT + "/" + process.env.REACT_APP_MERCHANT + "_logo.svg");
        return (
            <div>
                <Row>
                    <Col className="header-merchant-logo-div" xs={{span: 18, offset: 3}} sm={{span: 18, offset: 3}} md={{span: 18, offset: 3}} lg={{span:4, offset: 1}} xl={{span:4, offset: 1}}>
                        <img className="header-merchant-logo" src={logo} alt="MerchantLogo"/>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.CurrentRoute === "/" ? this.renderLandingPageHeader() : this.renderGeneralHeader()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default HeaderSto;
```

I have to mock the location (that should be easy) but I don't understand how should I specify to jest that the snapshot is not the same depending on that location...

I guess I explained everything, feel free to ask more details if needed.

Thanks for helping.
Have a nice day

Comment: What benefit does snapshot testing add to your app?

Comment: None. It's more a personal goal to better understand how it works. Right now I have the chance to work the way I want and to learn at the same time.

Comment: That is an awesome personal goal! My two cents is don't use snapshot testing. I find that it adds no value in that in two months you change a feature and are like well the snapshots don't match and I touched this file so obviously I need to update it vs unit/integration test where you say it should text this and if that breaks you know what it was testing and why.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Ould I appreciate if you're learning unit testing as per your goal.
Remember Jest has two type of testing SnapShot and component behaviour testing. We do snapshot testing for more like "How we structure our component". If make any changes in jsx structure it should not matches with the previous snapshot if any.

In your case There are two branches in your `HeaderSto` if you see your coverage report. Your need to make sure you test both cases to make **100%** coverage. Passing "/" one time and other time some other route to meet both conditions.

This is how we do snapshot testing :

```
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(
    <HeaderSto />
  ).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

**EDITED** Let's take an example to differentiate between snapshot vs Shallow/Mount testing strategies.

We have an app component:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <p className="App-intro" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          {data.appName}.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**SnapShot** Testing will result into this:

```
exports[`renders without crashing 1`] = `
<div
  className="App"
>
  <Header />
  <p
    className="App-intro"
    onClick={[Function]}
  >
    To get started, edit 
    <code>
      src/App.js
    </code>
     and save to reload.
  </p>
</div>
`;
```

and **Shallow** rendering would tell us how our component is behaving:
 we will mock data.appName and onClick method as our App expecting one prop appName and aslo we need to test it's handle click so we mock both of them:

```
const data = {
 appName: 'My App'
}
describe('HandleClick on P event success', () => {
 it('handleClick click invokes without throwing an error', () => {
    const handleClick = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(<App
      handleClick={handleClick}
       />);
    wrapper.find('.app').simulate('click');
    expect(handleClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Feel free to share any thoughts. Glad to help you with it.

Comment: Hi Sakhi, what is the diffrence between `renderer.create` and `shallow` ? Both render only the element right ? Looking at React documentation, `renderer.create` doesn't render the DOM, I don't understand when I should use one instead of the other. Thanks for helping !

Comment: Very interesting. We do it for two purposes. Snapshot will tell you how are you structuring your component html and shallow/mount will tell your component behiviour. See my EDITED answer above for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where your are using location function, it seems like `CurrentRoute` is just passed thru props. So just pass it inside your tests like that:

```
it("should render LandingPage header layout", () => {
    process.env.REACT_APP_MERCHANT = "merchant";
    const tree = shallow(<HeaderSto />);
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});

it("should render LandingPage header layout", () => {
    process.env.REACT_APP_MERCHANT = "merchant";
    const tree = shallow(<HeaderSto currentRoute="/some-other-path" />);
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped !